# Progressbar's progress not updating when inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        if(((i/dataArray.length)*100)%10 == 0)
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: (i / dataArray.length) * 100 });
        if (resultArray.indexOf(dataArray[i]) == -1) // check for duplicates
            resultArray.push(dataArray[i]);
}
```

I added the if statement because I dont want to keep updating the progress bar on each loop. the loop runs almost 222000 times. Is there a better logic to update the progress?

Why does it never enter the if statement?

Comment: Just a comment, you could cache `$("#progressbar")` in a variable outside the loop so you don't have to call it every loop.

Comment: what is dataArray ? show your markup .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, just a bit optimized from your code:

```
prog_bar = $("#progressbar");
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        if(i%100 == 0)
        prog_bar.progressbar({ value: (i / dataArray.length) * 100 });
        //other code..
}
```

Will you use a for loop? there is nothing "pausing" this loop so it will run very fast and you might just see it at 100%, instead of growing.

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Whdem/)**

You could instead call a function (instead of a for loop) to update the progress bar, as your "other code" is running:

```
var i = 0;
function update_progress_bar() {
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
        prog_bar.progressbar({
            value: (i / 10000) * 100
        });
    }
    i++;
}
```

Something like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZusg/2/)**

Comment: even if the other activities in the loop  takes time it will not show the progressbar because the UI thread will not get any time tp execute

Comment: @ArunPJohny Indeed I just thought about that. How would I fix that?

Comment: @Omar, it depends on your code, what is happening inside `//other code` ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, true. Added an alternative with a function call instead of loop.

Comment: how is calling a function and updating the ui there is different from updating ui in the if statement? I updated what othercode does

Comment: @Omar, if your "other code" is just what you posted, and no ajax or other script, it will run anyway very fast and the progress bar is unnecessary.