# Time counter Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, progress-bar

In my php application I get the numbers of seconds that remains to an event: ex: 6000sec.
and the total time since the creation of the event until the end. Ex: 10000sec.
I want to do a progress bar that take the seconds and, every second, atualize the progress bar.

Basically, I tried with `progressbar(), setInterval()` But i need help to do this.

```
$(function() {
var initial = 6000 // need to add seconds to this value every second.
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: initial,
  max: 10000
});
```

});

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yrErv/)

Comment: Check this answer [Progressbar's progress not updating when inside a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546552/progressbars-progress-not-updating-when-inside-a-loop)

Comment: you can do this with just CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and adjust the values to what you want:

```
$(function () {
    var current;
    var max = 10000;
    var initial = 6000; 
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: initial,
        max: max
    });

    function update() {
        current = initial; //the value on each function call
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: current
        });
        if (current >= max) clearInterval(interval);
        initial += 1000; //choose how fast to the number will grow
        console.log(current);
    };
    var interval = setInterval(update, 1000); //choose how fast to update
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HkkTm/1/)

Comment: Sorry, I need to add the value of initial every second until reach the max value.

Comment: @IgorMartins, sure. Were do you get that value from?

Comment: Via php.
I has the initial time, the final time. And ill pass the current time.
The time between initial and final its 10000seconds. And my final time LESS current time is = 6000 sec.
With 6000 seconds as initial time, i need to add this, every sec, +1 to count the progress bar.